# Accessing data from a ddr3

Tags: fpga, ram, ddr3, data-acquisition

I'am working on a new projet where I'm willing to access data from a ram, but the ram's specs is that they work with a frequency  up to 667MHz , so I decided to choose an FPGA to work as controller but every FPGA I've been seeing have only in theirs specifications "Internal clock speeds exceeding 450MHz" what does it even means Can I use this FPGAs or not will it cause any problem or nothing at all? if so How could I overcome it?

Just to say that I am beginner with FPGA's

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is the **Internal** part of "Internal clock speeds exceeding 450MHz". DDR clocks are typically considered external/'in-out'/IO clocks in this regard.

For off-chip connections like DDR3 you need to consult the IO specifications for your device. DDR3 being a type of 'DDR' double data rate of the internal clock rate implies ~450*2=900MHz upper limit. However, this will be very dependent on PCB trace lengths, outside the FPGA etc, dont expect that high. To that extent DDR3 - and other fancy fast IO like gigabit tranceivers (GTs) - are often mentioned specifically in data sheets like "High-performance SelectIO™ technology with support for DDR3 interfaces up to 800 Mb/s". And can compare that with rates quoted for your memory chip.